# Sending data to a url

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webclient, uploadstring

I want to send data to a php page, which inserts it in a database. I got the following code from [Sending data to php from windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759898/sending-data-to-php-from-windows-phone) from but it shows some errors:

1. On `using`: `System.Net.WebClient`: type used in a using statement
   must be implicitly convertible to `System.IDisposable`.
2. On `UploadString`: `System.Net.WebClient` does not contain a definition for `UploadString` and no extension method `UploadString`
   accepting a first argument of the type `System.Net.WebClient` could
   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
   reference?).

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

```
string URI = "http://www.myurl.com/post.php";
string myParameters = "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/writing-your-first-windows-8-app-the-lay/240143752 says `HttpClient` is replacing `WebClient` in windows 8 app

`Uploadstring` uses post method to send data and `PostAsync` is available in `HttpClient` which is what you might need.

try something like this.

```
using System.Net.Http;
//Windows.Web.Http 


string URI = "http://www.myurl.com/post.php";
string myParameters = "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3"; 

sendData(URI,myParameters);


public async void sendData(string URI,string myParameters)
 {
    using(HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
    {
        Var response = await hc.PostAsync(URI,new StringContent (myParameters));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I type `System.Net.`, it only 'accepts' `Browser`, `NetworkInformation` and `Sockets`. Nothing like `Http` or `HttpClient`..

Comment: @JelleKerkstra try Windows.Web.Http

Comment: this shows up: http://i811.photobucket.com/albums/zz38/JelleK1996/Untitled_zps70bd80c4.png

Comment: you should upgrade your .net to .net 4.5 and try again